# Convert Function in C# to NodeJS function

Tags: c#, node.js

I have an isue, I want to convert a function from C # to nodejs. but I still have some errors. i cant find the solution. i try to use some framework in nodejs but its still not working.
btw fyi, im used node-stringbuilder for stringbuilder.thanks for all your help

this is my function in C#

```
public static string ByteArrayToBase36String(byte[] bytes)
            {
                string ValidChars = "QAZ2WSX3" + "EDC4RFV5" + "TGB6YHN7" + "UJM8K9LP";
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();         // holds the base32 chars
                byte index;
                int hi = 5;
                int currentByte = 0;

                while (currentByte < bytes.Length)
                {
                    if (hi > 8)
                    {
                        index = (byte)(bytes[currentByte++] >> (hi - 5));
                        if (currentByte != bytes.Length)
                        {
                            index = (byte)(((byte)(bytes[currentByte] << (16 - hi)) >> 3) | index);
                        }    
                        hi -= 3;
                    }
                    else if (hi == 8)
                    {
                        index = (byte)(bytes[currentByte++] >> 3);
                        hi -= 3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        index = (byte)((byte)(bytes[currentByte] << (8 - hi)) >> 3);
                        hi += 5;
                    }
                    sb.Append(ValidChars[index]);
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
```

And this is my code in nodejs

```
function ByteArrayToBase36String(bytes)
 {
  var ValidChars = "QAZ2WSX3EDC4RFV5TGB6YHN7UJM8K9LP";
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  var index;
  var hi = 5;
  var currentByte = 0;
  while (currentByte < bytes.length) 
  {
    if (hi > 8) 
    {
      index = bytes[currentByte++] >> (hi - 5);
      
      if (currentByte != bytes.length)
      { 
        index =new Uint8Array((bytes[currentByte] << (16 - hi)) >> 3) | index; 
        console.log(index)  
      } 
      hi -= 3;
    }
    else if (hi == 8)
    {
      index = (bytes[currentByte++] >> 3)
      hi -= 3;
    }
    else
    {
      index = ((bytes[currentByte] << (8 - hi)) >> 3);
      hi += 5;
    }
    sb.append(ValidChars[index]);
  }
  return sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: Is `bytes` an array of numbers?

Comment: @Anatoly yes `bytes` is array

Comment: Why do you need `Buffer.from`?

Comment: @Anatoly im using `Buffer.from` instead of `byte []`

Comment: I don't see why you are using Buffer.from? You already have the array `bytes`.

Comment: @Anatoly ok bro thanks, the code not error again.  but the result still not same :(

Comment: I see the difference between C# `index = (byte)(((byte)(bytes[currentByte] << (16 - hi)) >> 3) | index)` and JS `index = bytes[currentByte] << (16 - hi) | index;` You missed `>> 3`

Comment: thanks a lot bro @Anatoly this problem is almost over. I have debugged one by one, and the problem occurs in this line.
`index =(new Int8Array((bytes[currentByte] << (16 - hi)) >> 3) | index); 
console.log(index)` the result in node js in this line is `2,0,6,1,3,0`
and the result in c# in this line is `10,28,6,5,3,10`
i dont know with the code in C# `(byte)(((byte)` its the mean what??
btw im edit my nodejs in the post with the last.

Comment: Yes `(byte)` can cut a value if it's greater than 255

Comment: @Anatoly then what should I use in nodejs?
because if in c # code `byte` i remove the result is same `938,220,1574,389,931,202`

Comment: To replace `(byte)aaa` you can do `aaa & 255`

Comment: In C# `> a = 65535
65535
> b = (byte)a
255
`

Comment: In JS `var a = 65535
a
65535
var b = a & 255
b
255`

Comment: I suppose by casting to `byte` you just leave lower 8 bits of a number and `& 255` does the same

Comment: WOWWW, Thank you very much bro @Anatoly you made my day so awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To emulate casting to `byte` `(byte)variable` just try to do `variable & 255` in JS.
That way you leave lower 8 bits of a number just like casting to byte does in C#.

P.S. And I suppose you don't need to use `Uint8Array`